# Find-S concept learning algorithm

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am implementing and analysing the Find-S Algorithm (which I understood quite well). However, for the testing part, I am not sure whether the order of the examples in the training set affect the output.

Is this known or still unproven?

Answer (score 0):

The order of examples will not affect the output if the function which expands the hypothesis is associative -- that is, if `f(f(h0),x1),x2) = f(f(h0,x2),x1)` for all `h0,x1,x2`.

Answer (score 0):

The order of instances will affect your output because when `FIND-S` try to maximally specific hypothesis, it looks attributes and their values. It is discussed in Tom Mitchell's Machine Learning Book under title of '2.4 FIND-S FINDING A MAXIMALLY SPECIFIC HYPOTHESIS'.